# Is it better to apply one thick or several thin layers of paint

Tags: painting

After hearing endless debates between my wife and myself, my son has decided to settle the question for his Science Fair project next year.  His experiment will determine whether one thick layer paint or several thinner layers of paint is more durable.

Using the tools available to a typical DIY'er, how can he apply a layer of paint with a consistent thickness?  Is there any reasonable way to make sure that the total thickness of the (say three) layers is the same as the one thick layer?

Comment: There is nothing to debate or settle. Several thin coats are better but ... for science!

Comment: Painters are not scientists, but they do great paint job. You cannot apply thick layer paint on rough surface. You cannot apply thick layer of slow drying paint on vertical surface without having it obeying the pull of gravity, thus, determining which type of layer(s) is more durable without considering surface type, paint type, weather, humidity and tools used is a bit subjective...!!

Comment: Now really:  this is **your kid's project** , not yours!  He should be developing his own criteria for "thick vs. thin" .  The important thing is for him to document his procedures and measurements.  Much as you want to help,  try to avoid doing so. (or you'll be on the path to becoming a helicopter parent!)

Comment: I agree with Carl Witthoft on letting your son do this project. Of course, if your **son** were to come here and ask for advice, saying "this is for my Science Fair project", I bet he'd get a whole lot of help. (My only assistance would be to suggest trying different painting methods and weighing/measuring the results to determine which left a thicker layer.)

Comment: Is spraying an option? With a spray gun, you could have samples where each received the same number of passes of the gun, but varied in drying between passes. E.g., sample 1 gets 5 passes, drying an hour between each, and sample 2 gets 5 passes all at once.

Comment: Downvote for misleadingly titled question.

Answer (score 2):

Science used to be considered an art... and I would bet that most scientists today would agree that it really is an art. I think that the best way to make sure it's nearly even is to use the same amount of paint over the same amount of area. In other words, use one cup of paint for each layer... or three cups of paint for one layer. Now most paint covers 600 sqft per gallon. So I would try spreading a cup of paint onto 36 square feet (that's 6 ft x 6 ft) and let nature run it's course (although it may take years). Alternatively you could try painting swatches of wood, and/or plastic, and or cloth, and/or aluminum, and/or any material.

Tips on painting and science:

1. Practice once or twice before starting.
2. If you start with a clean roller the first time, then start with a clean roller every time; or start with a used/precleaned roller... make sure that each painting job is handled "identically".
3. Purchase and use an accurate scale for weighing the paint and the roller (and maybe the swatch of wood). The idea is to make certain that each piece of wood gets the same amount of paint. But that's probably too tricky to get perfect. So, try to get it close, and record the actual amounts applied to the walls or swatches.
4. Make absolutely certain that the paint is very well mixed each time.
5. Record the weather conditions: sun, humidity, wind, time (at the time of painting, between coats, and over time as the wall or swatch is being weathered).
6. Subjecting different areas to different "accelerated" conditions will help fill out the results. In other words, allow some areas to age naturally, while other areas may be exposed to soil, or milk, or wet rags, and other areas could be solar irradiated, perhaps by adding reflectors. Other stressors might include an acid-wash treatment or a power washing every week. There should also be at least one section from each test that is kept from being exposed to any accelerating elements. Those would be the "control" sections for the experiment.
7. A time lapse camera (like for hunting) might be a good tool to have... once mounted it could be set to take a picture every day.
8. Replication is very important. For a good test, you would want at least four of each kind of "identical" test.
9. Consider the variety of paints and be write about why you chose to test whatever paint you test (any why not x, y, or z paint) and describe the kind of paint(s) with attention to details like the labeled application rate, color, composition, etc. Details might include: Gloss, Flat, Urthane, Oil, Acrylic, Latex, was primer used or recommended?, Aerosol, UV protection, Mildew resistant, Brand differences... it might be best to not mention any particular brand names, but you could mention relative price differences (which is information of value to most people).
10. Be sure to write the dates and identify/number the test articles on the swatches or wall (or on an attached tag), and keep a notebook with all the details and observations.

Answer (score 0):

A few pointers I would suggest:

Use a viscosity cup to measure paint thickness (viscosity) either to keep it consistent, or to change it to get a different thickness.

Use a simple comb type tool to measure wet film thickness.

**Experimentation** is not the most important part of science.  **Standing on the shoulders of giants** is.  Look at how [NASA tests paint](http://corrosion.ksc.nasa.gov/coatieval.htm).

Don Lancaster on [how to cut down bad science](http://www.tinaja.com/glib/bashpseu.pdf).  Not that your child should cut down bad science, but it shows how not to do bad science.

Comment: NASA refers (or defers) to American Society for Testing and Materials (ASTM). I might be willing to purchase the redline PDF version of [ASTM D1654](http://www.astm.org/search/fullsite-search.html?query=1654&) Standard Test Method for Evaluation of Painted or Coated Specimens Subjected to Corrosive Environments which only costs $7.80, just to see what the fuss is about; but [ASTM Volume 06.01 Paint](http://www.astm.org/BOOKSTORE/BOS/0601.htm) sells for around $300 - $400. IMHO, ASTM is not really worth the money, unless you have customers that will pay for ASTM testing methods.

Comment: Interesting.  Some may also find the link interesting. It's an entire web site at NASA, not a page, a site... Dedicated to corrosion protection, and mostly about coatings, and discusses the massive test facilities NASA operates.   Their business is, after all, maintaining massive outdoor steelwork in the most corrosive place in America, and they launch a few rockets on the side.  Kinda like Ford is a pension company that also makes cars.